# Functions with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x

My mini program takes a string from user input and adds dots between each letter and then removes these dots.

The function `add_dots` takes the string and adds dots. I have a separate function called `remove_dots` that then removes them.

Here is the code below:

```
def add_dots(str):
  str = ".".join(str)
  print(str)

def remove_dots(str):
  str.replace(".", "")
  print(str)

word = input("Enter a word: ")
```

When I call the two functions individually with

```
add_dots(word)
remove_dots(word)
```

I get the expected console output of

```
Enter a word: hello
h.e.l.l.o
hello
```

However, when I try to call

```
remove_dots(add_dots(word))
```

I get an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`

I understand that this means the `str` variable has the value of `None` but I'm not sure why? Can anyone advise. Thanks

Comment: Because your `add_dots` doesn't `return` anything, or more precisely, `return`ing `None`.

Comment: "add_dots" doesn't `return` anything, it only prints.

Comment: "I understand that this means the str variable has the value of None but I'm not sure why?" Well, what value do you think it should have? Why should it have that value? How do you expect the program to cause that to happen?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because your `add_dots` and `remove_dots` functions aren't actually returning anything, they're just printing values. Thus, passing the output of `add_dots` to `remove_dots` results in the value `None` being passed.

Also note that using `str` as a variable name is generally a bad idea; using `string` or a more descriptive name is better practice.

Change your code to return the modified strings, like so:

```
def add_dots(string):
  string = ".".join(string)
  return string

def remove_dots(string):
  string = string.replace(".", "")
  return string

word = input("Enter a word: ")
```

And print the outputs like so:

```
print(add_dots(word))
print(remove_dots(word))
print(remove_dots(add_dots(word)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_dots(str):
    str = ".".join(str)
    print(str)
    return str

def remove_dots(str):
    str = str.replace(".", "")
    print(str)
    return str
```

this should fix your code.

See @Chris and @Michael Butscher comments on your post

Comment: remove_dots() will return the input string in your answer.

Comment: Strings are never modified in-place, so in your answer, it needs to be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions don't return anything. Also, the output of `str.replace(".", "")` is not stored. This should work.

```
def add_dots(str):
  return ".".join(str)

def remove_dots(str):
  return str.replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return in something in function, You have to convert return in other datatype such as list , string. In this case, Your first function it should be

```
def add_dots(string):
  string = ".".join(string)
  print(string)
  return str(string)
```

And second function should be

```
 def remove_dots(string):
    string = string.replace(".", "")
    print(string)
    return str(string)
```

Because anything that return from function, It return "Nonetype" as default. And Nonetype no method `__getitem__`

ref:https://www.pythonpool.com/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable/